# Write to specific row in CSV according to query Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to lookup a value in my csv file and if I find it, write back a value at the end of its row.
For example, if the csv looks like this:

```
 #   A  B 
111  1
112  0
113  0
114  1
```

and I lookup 111 and want to write 0 in the first empty cell in its row, how can I do it?

Comment: so you want `111 1` to be like `111 1 0` or `111 0`? And each line will have only two values? seperated by `space`?

Comment: No No i want it to be 111 1 0, which means that the row will now have 3 values

Comment: @HamzaAhmad `First empty cell`: what is the separator? Tab or Space?

Comment: By the way, why are you using whitespace as the field delimiter in a CSV?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to insert data in the middle of a file. Writing to the middle of a file will overwrite the data at that position. Instead:

- open the file in read mode
- read all the data in the file
- close the file
- reopen the file in write mode
- write the first few lines
- write your extra data
- write the rest of the original data

an example:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
l = f.readlines()

l[4] += '0'
with open('test2.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(l)
```

Comment: @jarmod you are right, but this will overwrite existing data in that position. I will change the answer text

Comment: As a sidenote: for very large files, instead of re-writing the first n lines, you might want to *seek* to the correct position. But for most moderately sized files the approach in this answer will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('text.csv', 'r') as f:
    rows = [x.split() for x in f]
with open('text_1.csv', 'w') as f:
    for row in rows:
        f.write(row[0] + " " + row[1])
        if row[0] == '111': # or you can check for multiple values here.
            f.write("0")
        f.write("\n")
```

Comment: The `x.split()` approach to parsing csv files is a bad idea. The csv format is trickier than you think. Instead it's better to use the builtin csv package.

Comment: Or: rows = [x.split() for x in open('text.csv')]

Comment: @rje Can you please explain me on why `split` method might fail. Don't know/encountered major issues with it. Wanted to know.

Comment: There's several reasons. One is that you might have a quoted field containing a delimiter. In that case your method might fail.

Answer (score 0):

This will let you open, **read and write to the file within a single context manager** in one shot.

```py
search_term = '112' # This is what you are looking 
                    # for at the start of the lines.
##-------------------------------------------------------##
# Define separator
sep = '\t' # Use '\t' (TAB) or " " (SPACE)
val = 0 # This is the value you want to insert 
        # at the end of the target line.
##-------------------------------------------------------##
write_to_file = False # Set this to True when 
                      # you want to write to the file.

##-------------------------------------------------------##
with open("dummy.csv","r+") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for i,line in enumerate(content):
        if line.startswith(search_term):
            line = line.strip() + '{}{}\n'.format(sep,val)
            content[i] = line
    if write_to_file:
        f.writelines(content)

print(''.join(content))
```